# Definite clause grammar

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am trying to write a definite class grammar that takes a singleton list and determines if it is a 1 or 0.It keeps returning false and i can't figure out why it is not working.

```
zeroorone-->validnum.
validnum-->[0].
validnum-->[1].
```

Answer (score 0):

The language you've posted matches

0

and

1

but not

[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]

is that what you expected?

phrase(zeroorone, X).
should respond

X = [0].
X = [1].

Now, it's also possible that you're confusing 'code' style Prolog strings

"100" with [1,0,0]
The former is ['1', '0', '0']

An example of your code failing would be useful

Answer (score 0):

Anniepoo is right. This works in SWI-Prolog.

I put your code into a file a.pl and load it using consult(a). Then I can run the following.

```
zeroorone([0], []).
true .

zeroorone([1], []).
true .
```

And as Anniepoo said running the following works after you press enter and then space to get the second answer

```
phrase(zeroorone, X).
X = [ 0 ] ;
X = [ 1 ].
```

However, as she said it does not work for anything but the two lists [ 0 ] and [ 1 ].

e.g.

```
zeroorone([1,0,0], []).
false.
```

In order to get a better answer you may need to specify what is actually required.